# Angular Lazy loaded module - Issue in my route with a param

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

I have three modules (sorry, it is in french) :
- dashboard
- devis
- famille.
These modules are lazy loaded :

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
  { path: 'devis', loadChildren: 'app/devis/devis.module#DevisModule' },
  { path: 'famille', loadChildren: 'app/famille/famille.module#FamilleModule' },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: Error404PageComponent,
    resolve: { data: Error404PageResolver }
  },
  {
    // There's a bug that's preventing wild card routes to be lazy loaded (see: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13848)
    // That's why the Error page should be eagerly loaded
    path: '**',
    component: Error404PageComponent,
    resolve: { data: Error404PageResolver }
  }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
    useHash: false
  }) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

My "Famille" route file is like this :

```
const familleRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            { 
                path: ':id',
                component: FamilleComponent,     
                resolve: { utilisateur: AuthResolver, dossierFamille: DossierFamilleResolver, referentiel: ReferentielFamilleResolver, informationFamille: InformationFamilleResolver, droits: DroitFamilleResolver }
            },
            { 
                path: '', 
                component: FamilleComponent,
                resolve: { utilisateur: AuthResolver, referentiel: ReferentielFamilleResolver , droits: DroitFamilleResolver } 
            }
        ]
    }
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(familleRoutes)],
    providers: [AuthResolver, DossierFamilleResolver, ReferentielFamilleResolver, InformationFamilleResolver, DroitFamilleResolver, AuthService],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FamilleRoutingModule { }
```

I try also this version:

```
const familleRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: FamilleComponent,
        resolve: { utilisateur: AuthResolver, referentiel: ReferentielFamilleResolver , droits: DroitFamilleResolver }
    },
    {
        path: ':id',
        component: FamilleComponent,     
        resolve: { utilisateur: AuthResolver, dossierFamille: DossierFamilleResolver, referentiel: ReferentielFamilleResolver, informationFamille: InformationFamilleResolver, droits: DroitFamilleResolver }
    }    
];
```

And my "devis" route is mostly the same. 
Each time, it is the same component to create a "famille" or a "devis" and display a "famille" or "devis" : FamilleComponent and DevisComponent.

```
const devisRoutes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '', 
        component: DevisComponent, resolve: { utilisateur: AuthResolver, referentiel: ReferentielDevisResolver, droits: DroitsDevisResolver }
    },
    { 
        path: ':id', 
        component: DevisComponent, 
        resolve: { utilisateur: AuthResolver, devis: DevisResolver, referentiel: ReferentielDevisResolver, droits: DroitsDevisResolver }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(devisRoutes)],
    providers: [DevisResolver, ReferentielDevisResolver, DroitsDevisResolver, AuthResolver, AuthService],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DevisRoutingModule { }
```

My problem is when I try to go to the url localhost:4200/famille, in my famille.resolver, the value of route.params.id is "famille".
I would like this value empty.

And if I try the url localhost:4200/famille/1234567, the value of route.params.id is my id : 1234567.

Without lazy loading of the module, it is working fine. So I don't understand what is wrong.

And I have also something wired. I mean when I try to go to the url 
localhost:4200/devis, the method resolve of the class InformationFamilleResolver is called !

Do you have any idea of the problem?

Thank you for your help,
Adrien